# File drag and drop in input box with label tag

Tags: javascript, html, image, drag-and-drop, hex

I created a site where you can upload an image and then after clicking on an image point, the site will return the HEX code of the point you clicked.

You can click on the input box (button) in order to upload the image but I also wanted to make it work after dragging-dropping the image.

I am using a label to make the button look beautiful. So, I have a script that is hiding the input box :

```
<script>
    (function(e,t,n){
        var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];
        r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2")
    })
    (document,window,0);
</script>
```

And the equivalent HTML line is :

```
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
```

This is the HTML script for the input box and the label :

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload[]" id="file_upload" class="inputfile inputfile-2" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple />
<label for="file_upload">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg> 
    <span>CHOOSE A FILE</span>
</label>
```

If I remove the label and unhide the input box then the drag and drop works fine as it should.

Now, I am trying to make it work after dragging-dropping a file in this box :
[image]

The snippet is below :

```js
//Script that hides the input box (label is a substitute)
(function(e,t,n){var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2")})(document,window,0);

//Hex picker function
var $picked = $("#picked"); // Just to preview picked colors
 var canvas = $('#canvas_picker')[0];
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


 $("#file_upload").change(function (e) {
   var F = this.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
   reader.readAsDataURL(F);  
 });

 function imageIsLoaded(e) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function(){
  canvas.width  = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   };
   img.src = e.target.result;
 }

 $('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){
   var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
   var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
   var img_data = context.getImageData(x,y , 1, 1).data;
   var R = img_data[0];
   var G = img_data[1];
   var B = img_data[2]; 
   var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B ;
   var hex = rgbToHex(R,G,B);
   $('#rgb input').val( rgb );
   $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
   $picked.append("<span style='background:#"+hex+"'>#"+hex+"</span>");
 });

 function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
   return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B);
 }

 function toHex(n) {
   n = parseInt(n, 10);
   if (isNaN(n))  return "00";
   n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
   return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16)  + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
 }
```

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/EsvMC5un3kjyUhB9ZEPPwg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

body {
    background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
    font-family: 'Lato';
    color: #000;
    font: 15px/1.4em;
}

canvas{
  background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
 
}

#picked span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  font:8px/50px Arial;
  color:#fff;
}

.js .inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputfile + label {
    max-width: 80%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
}

.no-js .inputfile + label {
    display: none;
}

.inputfile:focus + label,
.inputfile.has-focus + label {
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}


.inputfile + label svg {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: currentColor;
    margin-top: -0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
}


.inputfile-2 + label {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 220px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 3px solid #333;
}



/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col2 {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0;
}
.col2:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group2:before,
.group2:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group2:after { clear:both;}
.group2 { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.66%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 33.33%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col2 {  margin: 0 }
 .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}


/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.5%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.5%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}


/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 margin-left:5%;
 margin-right:5%;
 clear: both;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.5%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.5%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<div id="picked"></div>
 <div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_4">
   <input type="file" name="file_upload[]" id="file_upload" class="inputfile inputfile-2" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple /><label for="file_upload"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg><span>CHOOSE A FILE</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_3_of_4">
      <canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas_picker"></canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <html/>
```

Comment: Jdfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40ekn7ym/

Comment: @TraeAbell It is exactly the same code I provided. Did you miss something?

Comment: I set up the fiddle to help anyone working on solving this for you, I didn't have the time to do more myself.

Comment: @TraeAbell Ok. Fair enough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry for code formatting, i don't have much time and it took me a little search fo find, but your solution is elegant so i thought it was worth.
here is what i gathered from my last drag'n'drop experiment:

- it seems that you need to cancel these 2 other drag events to capture correctly the drop event
- you need to grab the `originalEvent` to get the files
- Also just found out that file inputs values are not editable for security reasons, but you can redraw directly from what you have. Maybe there's a solution to delegate the event, but i won't check this just now.

**Note:** on a local page, with jQuery and styles in the header, and script in a `$(document).ready and after the html, the input didn't disappear (same, i don't have time to check why)

```js
//Script that hides the input box (label is a substitute)
(function(e,t,n){var r=e.querySelectorAll("html")[0];r.className=r.className.replace(/(^|\s)no-js(\s|$)/,"$1js$2")})(document,window,0);

//Hex picker function
var $picked = $("#picked"); // Just to preview picked colors
 var canvas = $('#canvas_picker')[0];
 var context = canvas.getContext('2d');


 $("#file_upload").change(function (e) {
   var F = this.files[0];
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
   reader.readAsDataURL(F);  
 });

$('#fileLabel').bind({
 dragover: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 },
 dragleave: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
 },
 drop: function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
  var F = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0];
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
  reader.readAsDataURL(F);
 }
});

 function imageIsLoaded(e) {
   var img = new Image();
   img.onload = function(){
  canvas.width  = this.width;
  canvas.height = this.height;
  context.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
   };
   img.src = e.target.result;
 }

 $('#canvas_picker').click(function(event){
   var x = event.pageX - $(this).offset().left;
   var y = event.pageY - $(this).offset().top;
   var img_data = context.getImageData(x,y , 1, 1).data;
   var R = img_data[0];
   var G = img_data[1];
   var B = img_data[2]; 
   var rgb = R + ',' + G + ',' + B ;
   var hex = rgbToHex(R,G,B);
   $('#rgb input').val( rgb );
   $('#hex input').val('#' + hex);
   $picked.append("<span style='background:#"+hex+"'>#"+hex+"</span>");
 });

 function rgbToHex(R, G, B) {
   return toHex(R) + toHex(G) + toHex(B);
 }

 function toHex(n) {
   n = parseInt(n, 10);
   if (isNaN(n))  return "00";
   n = Math.max(0, Math.min(n, 255));
   return "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt((n - n % 16) / 16)  + "0123456789ABCDEF".charAt(n % 16);
 }
```

```css
/* latin-ext */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/dPJ5r9gl3kK6ijoeP1IRsvY6323mHUZFJMgTvxaG2iE.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+1E00-1EFF, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'), url(http://fonts.gstatic.com/s/lato/v11/EsvMC5un3kjyUhB9ZEPPwg.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2212, U+2215, U+E0FF, U+EFFD, U+F000;
}

body {
    background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
    font-family: 'Lato';
    color: #000;
    font: 15px/1.4em;
}

canvas{
  background: hsl(184,65%,49%);
 
}

#picked span{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
  margin:3px;
  text-align:center;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 1px #000;
  font:8px/50px Arial;
  color:#fff;
}

.js .inputfile {
    width: 0.1px;
    height: 0.1px;
    opacity: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}

.inputfile + label {
    max-width: 80%;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0.625rem 1.25rem;
}

.no-js .inputfile + label {
    display: none;
}

.inputfile:focus + label,
.inputfile.has-focus + label {
    outline: 1px dotted #000;
    outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 5px;
}


.inputfile + label svg {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    vertical-align: middle;
    fill: currentColor;
    margin-top: -0.25em;
    margin-right: 0.25em;
}


.inputfile-2 + label {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 220px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #333;
    border: none;
    font-family: Lato;
 text-align: center;
    font-size: 1vw;
    padding: 25px 0 25px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    font-weight: 700;
    outline: none;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s;
    transition: all 0.3s;
    border: 3px solid #333;
}



/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col2 {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 0;
}
.col2:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group2:before,
.group2:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group2:after { clear:both;}
.group2 { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }

/*  GRID OF THREE  */
.span_3_of_3 { width: 100%; }
.span_2_of_3 { width: 66.66%; }
.span_1_of_3 { width: 33.33%; }

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col2 {  margin: 0 }
 .span_3_of_3, .span_2_of_3, .span_1_of_3 { width: 100%; }
}


/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.5%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.5%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}


/*  SECTIONS  */
.section {
 margin-left:5%;
 margin-right:5%;
 clear: both;
}

/*  COLUMN SETUP  */
.col {
 display: block;
 float:left;
 margin: 1% 0 1% 2%;
}
.col:first-child { margin-left: 0; }

/*  GROUPING  */
.group:before,
.group:after { content:""; display:table; }
.group:after { clear:both;}
.group { zoom:1; /* For IE 6/7 */ }
/*  GRID OF FOUR  */
.span_4_of_4 {
 width: 100%;
}
.span_3_of_4 {
 width: 74.5%;
}
.span_2_of_4 {
 width: 49%;
}
.span_1_of_4 {
 width: 23.5%;
}

/*  GO FULL WIDTH BELOW 480 PIXELS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 .col {  margin: 1% 0 1% 0%; }
 .span_1_of_4, .span_2_of_4, .span_3_of_4, .span_4_of_4 { width: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<html lang="en" class="no-js">

<div id="picked"></div>
 <div class="section group">
  <div class="col span_1_of_4">
      <input type="file" name="file_upload[]" id="file_upload" class="inputfile inputfile-2" data-multiple-caption="{count} files selected" multiple /><label id="fileLabel" for="file_upload"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="20" height="17" viewBox="0 0 20 17"><path d="M10 0l-5.2 4.9h3.3v5.1h3.8v-5.1h3.3l-5.2-4.9zm9.3 11.5l-3.2-2.1h-2l3.4 2.6h-3.5c-.1 0-.2.1-.2.1l-.8 2.3h-6l-.8-2.2c-.1-.1-.1-.2-.2-.2h-3.6l3.4-2.6h-2l-3.2 2.1c-.4.3-.7 1-.6 1.5l.6 3.1c.1.5.7.9 1.2.9h16.3c.6 0 1.1-.4 1.3-.9l.6-3.1c.1-.5-.2-1.2-.7-1.5z"/></svg><span>CHOOSE A FILE</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col span_3_of_4">
      <canvas width="600" height="300" id="canvas_picker"></canvas>
  </div>
 </div>
  
  <html/>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks. I will keep the script in the html file for now. I will raise another question in case I want to change it. Next challenge --> Time to find a way to create batch files to change sub-folders icons. Thanks again.